# "Do until" loop in a Stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm pretty new to all this about Stored Procedures..
What i want to accomplish is a query and then loop thru all the returned rows..
I thought about somting like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_findDoor
@door int,
AS
DECLARE @foundId int
SELECT @foundId=Id FROM pd_orders WHERE door=@door
```

For each id in above Query i want to delete in another table like this

```
DELETE FROM pd_md_detials WHERE order_id = @foundId
```

Now i do all this by ASP code and it looks like this

```
Set db = con.execute("Select id from pd_orders WHERE door=1")
Do UNTIL db.EOF
  Con.execute("DELETE FROM pd_md_details WHERE order_id="& db("id"))
  db.movenext
LOOP
```

Is this even possible in a SP or do i have to rethink?

***Edited Section***

If i have tables on three levels like

`pd_order_ecolid  -> pd_mounting_details  -> pd_inventory`

And the related columns for above tables are

`ID   ->  order_data   -> pp_id`

Then it should be possible with this line to delete all rows in table pd_inventory

```
DELETE FROM pd_inventory
WHERE pp_id IN 
  (
     SELECT id FROM pd_mounting_details 
     WHERE order_data IN 
       (
         SELECT id from pd_order_ecolid 
         WHERE order_head=@order_head AND order_line=@order_line
       )
  )
```

im not able to try it myself seens im not athome (but i cant stop thinking about how to fix this)

Best regards

Comment: I think that you are looking for a `CURSOR`

Comment: you dont need a loop for that.. try this.. `delete to_be_deleted_table where id in (select id from pd_colors where door = @door)`

Comment: "do i have to rethink?" - yes, SQL is a set oriented language, for the most part. You'd generally describe the whole operation and let the server work out how best to perform it (such as by looping, etc). It sounds like you just need something like `DELETE FROM <Table> WHERE <ID> in (select Id from pd_colors WHERE door=@door)`

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer, i never used "IN" but i'm going to google it and se what it is..

Answer (score 0):

Am i missing something? You want to DELETE every record `WHERE door=@door` ?

Why not change your SQL:

`DELETE FROM pd_colors WHERE door=@door` - This deletes the tuple

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to delete where `door=@door` you can just;

`delete from pd_colors where door=@door`

If you want to loop to combine a fetch of the deleted rows you can instead;

`delete from pd_colors output deleted.* where door=@door`